# Rails : Controller/Create - How to write an if create success

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am currently building an app that uses stripe, when a payment is successful the user follows *redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)*. How do I control where the user goes when the payment is declined or there is an error?

Perhaps I need an if statement? If success?

```
  def create

    @account = User.find_by_id(params[:account_id])
    key = @account.access_code
    Stripe.api_key = key
    account_suid = @account.uid
    @order = Order.find(params[:order])
    charge = @order.amount * 100
    fee = @order.amount * 1
  
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: @order.email, source: token)
 
     Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
       customer: customer,
       amount: (charge).to_i, 
       confirm: true,
       currency: 'gbp',
       payment_method_types: ['card'],
       application_fee_amount: (fee).to_i,
     }, {
       stripe_account: account_suid
     })
    options = {
      stripe_id: customer.id
    }

    options.merge!(
      card_last4: params[:user][:card_last4],
      card_exp_month: params[:user][:card_exp_month],
      card_exp_year: params[:user][:card_exp_year],
      card_type: params[:user][:card_brand]
    )

    OrderFiniJob.perform_now(@order)
    redirect_to session.delete(:return_to), notice: "Your order has been successful "
    
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

When an error occurs or the payment is declined, stripe raises an exception ([some stripe erros](https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes)).
So, you could rescue the error and respond what you want, for example 400

```
def create
  ...
  redirect_to ...

rescue Stripe::StripeError
  render status: :bad_request
end
```